# Calculate shipping cost using two "flat" rates and one variable rate

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and learning C# and am a bit stuck. I am trying to set two flat rates and one variable rate in reference to the following:

> shipping is  3.50$ for 5 pounds or below, 10$ for  20 pounds or below,
>   [example: 10 pound weight: shipping is 10$. 4 pounds weight: 3.5$]
>   9.5$ plus 10c per pound,  for weights above 20 pounds. (two flat rates and one variable rate)

This is what I currently have (its a mess):

```
//Declorations

int artDbl, carrDbl, beetDbl;
double resultInt, result1Dbl, result2Dbl,totalresultDbl; 
double artRate = 2.67, carrRate = 1.49, beetRate = .67;
//double discountDbl;
//double discountRate = 0.05;
decimal totalweightDbl;
//double shiprateDbl = 3.50, shiprate1Dbl = 10.00, shiprate2Dbl = 9.50, shiprate3Dbl = 0.10;
decimal totalshipDbl;
//var shipcostVar;

String outputString;    

//Inputs
artDbl = int.Parse(artBox.Text);
carrDbl = int.Parse(carrBox.Text);
beetDbl = int.Parse(beetBox.Text);

    //Results for weight multiplied by rate per pound
resultInt = artDbl * artRate;
result1Dbl = carrDbl * carrRate;
result2Dbl = beetDbl * beetRate;
totalweightDbl = artDbl + carrDbl + beetDbl;

//shipcostVar = totalweightDbl * .10;
// Results for total weight of all three items
totalresultDbl = resultInt + result1Dbl + result2Dbl;   

//Outputs
outputString = totalresultDbl.ToString("C");
textBox4.Text = totalresultDbl.ToString("C");


if (totalweightDbl <= 5)
{ totalshipDbl = 3.50m; }
else if (totalweightDbl <= 20)
{ totalshipDbl = 10.00m; }


//textBox5.Text = totalshipDbl.ToString("C");
```

Comment: I have no clue about what variable means in your code, i.e. what `artDbl` means, what `carrDbl` means.

Comment: hi, these are the whole numbers entered into the textbox. If customer enters 10 into artDbl it multiplies it by artRate for resultInt. I'm sure this is all very confusing looking at it all.

Comment: @rpdeleon, has this been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Had to do the same for a shipping company. Here is how the requirement was satisfied.

Model used to store rates.

```
public class Rate {
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> basePrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> baseWeight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> unitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> unitWeight { get; set; }
}
```

From there collection can be used to hold rules for rates that were loaded from persistence store.

```
rates = new List<Rate>();
rates.Add(new Rate { weight = 5, basePrice = 3.50M });
rates.Add(new Rate { weight = 20, basePrice = 10M });
rates.Add(new Rate { weight = int.MaxValue, basePrice = 9.50M, baseWeight = 20, unitPrice = 0.10M, unitWeight = 1 });
```

The above shows the requirements of rates in original example. The `weight` and `basePrice` should be self explanatory. As you can see there are two flat rates for weights up to 5 and 20 pounds. The `baseWeight`, `unitPrice`, and `unitWeight` are used to calculate the cost of variable weight if needed.

The algorithm used to calculate rate based on total weight and available rates

```
public decimal? CalculateRate(int totalweight, IList<Rate> lookup) {
    decimal? result = null;

    var availableRates = lookup.OrderBy(r => r.weight);

    var rate = availableRates.FirstOrDefault(r => totalweight <= r.weight) ?? availableRates.LastOrDefault();

    if (rate != null) {
        if (rate.baseWeight != null) {

            var baseRate = rate.basePrice;

            var weighDiff = totalweight - rate.baseWeight.GetValueOrDefault();

            var weightDiffUnits = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)weighDiff / (double)rate.unitWeight.GetValueOrDefault());

            var pricePerDiff = rate.unitPrice.GetValueOrDefault();

            var weightDiffRate = weightDiffUnits * pricePerDiff;

            result = baseRate + weightDiffRate;
        } else {
            result = rate.basePrice;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The following unit tests were done to verify algorithm

```
[TestMethod]
public void When_4_Pounds() {
    //Arrange
    var totalWeight = 4;
    var expected = 3.5M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateRate(totalWeight, rates);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void When_Ten_Pounds() {
    //Arrange
    var totalWeight = 10;
    var expected = 10M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateRate(totalWeight, rates);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void When_Thirty_Pounds() {
    //Arrange
    var totalWeight = 30;
    var expected = 10.5M;

    //Act
    var actual = CalculateRate(totalWeight, rates);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

If rates change then update the collection with new values.

Comment: As it was pointed out in the question, that the author is pretty new to C#, I would suggest to not use LINQ. It gets really confusing when you're new to this language. The rest looks fine to me.